# scheduleAtFixedRate() is being called twice

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Logs:

[pool-1-thread-1] TRACE apns.ApnsPushConnection - Enter Method queryFeedbackService params
[pool-3-thread-1] TRACE apns.ApnsPushConnection - Enter Method queryFeedbackService params
[pool-1-thread-1] TRACE apns.ApnsPushConnection - Return Method queryFeedbackService
[pool-3-thread-1] TRACE apns.ApnsPushConnection - Return Method queryFeedbackService

```
//In Singleton class constructor
ScheduledExectorService obj = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();


obj.scheduleAtFixedDelay(new runnable(){

     public void run(){ 
     classObj.queryFeedbackService();
}  
}),20,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);     



//method called by thread      
public void queryFeedbackService()
{

     code here

}
```

Comment: please post your code..

Comment: Hi redflar3, please go through my comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there was 2 pools as per answered by Jean.

But in my case here, my project is loaded into Jetty server which was initialized by Spring.

Also inside Jetty server - it was creating container for Spring beans that were getting initialized from service-context.xml file.

So It was getting called twice that leads to the creation of two pools

Thanks you all those who commented and tried solve my issue.
Means a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

From the log, you have several several pools running: `pool-1` and `pool-3`.

You might want to make sure you only initialize one pool.

Comment: Yeah Jean, You are right. But I am not getting how it is happenning.

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService obj = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); That's how I initialized it

Comment: But are you sure this piece of code is called only once?

Comment: `But I am not getting how it is happenning.` Without code, we can't figure it out

Comment: you are right jhamon, but code is bit scattered through different places. To be precise, In my singleton class constructor, i have created object as I commented above. then called obj.scheduleAtFixedRate(feedbackListener, 20, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); feedbacklistener is thread which calls the method as showed in logs

Comment: @GauravKamble You clearly have several pools running. You need to investigate that. Try debugging your code to track when the code is being called.

Comment: I did that Jean. while debugging it called only once.